# cannot manipulate a dictionary data from Django inside the template

Tags: html, django, django-views

in my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.

def home(req):
    a={'a':1,'c':5}
    return render(req,'index.html',{'a':a})
```

in my template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
 <!-----Server data----->
   
<body>
    <p>{{a['a']}}</p>
    
</body>
</html>
```

it gives me a template error, why i can't subscript the dic?

Comment: Becuase the Django template language is restricted to not allow subscripting.

Comment: Key lookups can be performed with the "dot" syntax: `{{ a.a }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It gives me a template error, why i can't subscript the dictionary?

Because the Django template language is restricted to not allow subscripting. This is to discourage writing business logic in the template.

If however the subscript is a string, you can access it with a dot, for example here:

```
<p>{{ a.a }}</p>
```

If you write `{{ x.y }}`, then Django will try to perform a subscript (so `x['y']`), an attribute lookup (so `x.y`) (and call the method with no parameters if it is a callable), and finally a numerical lookup (so `x[int(y)]`).

This is specified in the [*Variables* section of the Django documentation on the template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/language/#variables).